# Можно ли визуализировать связи данных между двумя таблицами?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, визуализация

Есть 2 таблицы attributes и attribute_attributes_connections в postgres, построена связь many to many:

[image: Таблицы]

Можно ли как-то визуализировать данные в таблицах? Что-то типа того:

[image: Пример визуализации]

Answer (score 0):

В принципе это сделать реально написав небольшой скрипт и через Navicat for PostgreSQL вывести, но выглядит это все не очень:

[image]